# Onload function not triggered from js file

Tags: javascript, html, django, onload

When I run window.onload function from .js file, the function is not triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jscode.js' %}"></script>

    window.onload = function() {
    alert('Page is loaded');
    };
```

However, onload is working as expected when put along a seperate script tag or into body onload

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
        alert('Page is loaded');
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jscode.js' %}"></script>
```

In my jscode.js are other functions that work fine except for triggering the onload. I tired jQuery code, js code etc. Only putting the scrpit tag in html line seems to be working but it is not what I tend to achieve.

Is there something I am missing for the onload to trigger? I use django to create my website.

Comment: ok is there any warning on console ? is your js file loading correctly ? to check it you can plae an alert in js cod directlye and test it out if it is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out static was a part of cookies and even though I have updated the js file the browser was still using the previous not updated version. Clearing browser data helped and Chrome loaded the updated js file from django.